# Hostgator redirect main folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-routing, hosting, web-hosting

I'm having problems with folder hierarchy or .htaccess on Hostgator.

Today I'm using something like this inside the public folder

- public_html

  - domain1(primary/main domain of my account in Hostgator)

    - app

      - index.html
  - otherdomain

But when I access the domain1 website I get the following URL

```
domain1.com/domain1.com/app/index.html
```

i found that i have a htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /domain1.com/$1
```

Apparently the main domain of the HostGator account should be placed directly on public_html, otherwise, I need the .htaccess to redirect.

What can I do to have a shorter URL like this: http://domain1.com/app/index.html and don't place domain1 directly on `public_html`?

Comment: Do you know what's the idea of your htaccess file is: remove www before the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply the last line. Change it like that:

```
RewriteRule (.*) $1
```

However, it is not clear what your htaccess file actually tries to achieve. This change might break other things. Check if you can still access special pages/cpaneldcv.